# How to set antialiasing on or off in a SwiftUI Canvas

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-graphics

How do I turn antialiasing on or off in a SwiftUI Canvas?

```
struct CanvasView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            // CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "global" switch in `GraphicsContext` that turns antialiasing on and off. Instead antialiasing can be controlled individually for each draw operation that takes a [`FillStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fillstyle). You can specify whether you want antialiasing when creating the `FillStyle`.

For example:

```
context.fill(
    somePath, with: .color(someColor), 
    fillStyle: .init(antialiased: false)
)
```

Otherwise, you can always get a `CGContext` and work with the `CGContext` APIs instead.

```
context.withCGContext { cgContext in
    cg.setShouldAntialias(false)
    // do the rest of your drawing here...
}
```

The stroking APIs don't take a `FillStyle`, so if you want to configure antialiasing for those, you will need to use the `CGContext` APIs, or convert the stroking operation to a fill operation, by using [`strokedPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/strokedpath(_:)):

```
let pathToStroke: Path = ...
let strokeStyle = StrokeStyle(...)
context.fill(path.strokedPath(strokeStyle), with: someColor, style: FillStyle(antialiased: false))
```

Comment: Ok! Using `fillStyle: .init(antialiased: false)` works however there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for `context.stroke`? If I stroke a path it uses the last antialiased setting from the fillStyle.

Comment: @BerryBlue there isn’t an option for `stroke`. I think Apple might have forgotten to add that. Anyway stroking a path is equivalent to filling the path you get from calling [`strokedPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/strokedpath(_:)) on the path you want to stroke. Just do that instead.

Comment: @BerryBlue or just use the `CGContext` instead. I find that way more useful unless you are drawing text/images/symbols. Lots of existing APIs take `CGContext`s anyway.